# My data from database is coming (as it shows data outside my form), but not displaying through AJAX. in a proper location

Tags: ajax, mongodb, codeigniter

This is my controller , where i am loading my model and storing data in $result

**Controller**

```
public function masteradmin()
    {       
            $result= $this->AppconfigModel->showAllMasterAdmin();
            echo json_encode($result);

    }
```

In my model , i am using mongodb driver class for making connection. Here i am retriving data where first name is mukesh.

**Model**

```
public function ShowAllMasterAdmindata()
{
    $mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');

    $filter = ['fullname' => 'mukesh'];
    $options =[];

    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
    $result = $mongo->executeQuery('justrack_db.master_admin', $query); 
    foreach($result as $r){
        $r = json_decode(json_encode($r),true);
        return $r;
    }
}
```

This is my Ajax code , where i am retrieving data from database. I tried alert statement to debug, but nothing is showing. What's wrong i am doing

**Ajax**

```
     <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">

        $(function(){
                showAllMasterAdmin();


        function showAllMasterAdmin() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Appconfig/showAllMasterAdmin',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data){

                var html= '';
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    alert(data[i].fullname);
                    html+ ='<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].fullname+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].username+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].designation+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].department+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].official_mobile_no+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].official_email_id+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].select_user_type+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].permission+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>' 
                }
                $('#showdata').html(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not get data from database');
            }
        });
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: try :   echo json_encode($result);

Comment: Thank u Manoj Singh

Comment: Doubt is AJAX is not displaying data